# Site gets 1 heavy use day per year - how do i tune for it

Tags: multithreading, apache, performance, load, clients

I run a site as a service for the statewide high school swimming community.  I do this for love of the sport, so I can't spend a ridiculous sum on hosting, etc.  Nor do I need to - except for one day a year.

The coaches all submit their regional entries through my site, and in typical fashion all wait until the due date to do it.  That was yesterday, and my site which never fell over all season ground to an unresponsive halt at least 4 times throughout the day.  It was never gone for more than an hour, and it always came back.  (I issued apache restarts just to be sure).

My question is: how can I tune Apache to handle a one day surge of users?  It makes no sense to pay for more hardware for an entire year when I only need to caox one day of increased performance.  I've tried reading about prefork.c and worker.c but I just don't understand it well enough.  Here's my current config:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
 StartServers       1
 MinSpareServers    1
 MaxSpareServers    5
 ServerLimit       10
 MaxClients        10
 MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule worker.c>
 StartServers       1
 MaxClients        10
 MinSpareThreads    1
 MaxSpareThreads    4
 ThreadsPerChild     25
 MaxRequestsPerChild  0
 </IfModule>
```

The most users I would ever expect at once would be 400.  Likely much less than that though.  I only had about 70 yesterday and it didn't perform very well.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean tuning the Apache *httpd* Web Server? That would be off-topic here. This site is for programming questions, not server admin.

Comment: There are literally scores and scores of httpd server admin-type questions on this site.  Why is this off-topic?  More importantly, where should I ask this question?

Comment: See the Help section, [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) – see point # 6. When voting to close a Question, Stack Overflow offers a category precisely for this particular misfit: *Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.*